# OpenLayers 3: Geometric OGC filters

Tags: openlayers, wfs, openlayers-2, gml, ogc

How do I generate geometric OGC filters for use in a [WFS GetFeature](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html) request such as:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:Intersects>
        <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Box xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
            <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">1298543.0367787,7107400.531374 1299312.4070614,7203464.9016567</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:Box>
    </ogc:Intersects>
</ogc:Filter>
```

The OpenLayers 2 supported geometric filters (e.g., Intersections). How do I write a filter in the OL3?
[`ol.format.ogc.filter`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.ogc.filter.html) seems does not support (geometric filters).

Comment: for just a bbox filter you can use the --> http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.ogc.filter.Bbox.html

Comment: Truly, but this is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the library has changed over the time, you can now provide filters for spatial operations using `ol.format.filter.*` functions (previously in the namespace `ol.format.ogc.filter.*`)

Using something like below will work:

```
  var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
  srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
  featureNS: 'http://openstreemap.org',
  featurePrefix: 'osm',
  featureTypes: ['water_areas'],
  outputFormat: 'gml3',
  filter: ol.format.filter.and(
    ol.format.filter.intersects('the_geom', polygon, 'EPSG:4326'),
    ol.format.filter.equalTo('waterway', 'riverbank')
  )
});
```

where `polygon` is an `ol.geom.Geometry`.

Be aware that I had to invert X and Y coordinates in my `polygon` to make things working correctly.

You can see [an example in action](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/530d830eca124cc1b836ff341bc63da6) to illustrate (PS: working in Chrome, not in FF, didn't debug more because do not own the remote server...).

Comment: Yes, it is I myself added to the library - not previously... In any case, thank you